# Iterating over model constraints in bulk data create on Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to save data from an API with constant live updates. Hence, the data from the API will always container an existing dataset on my database. So I created a unique_together to prevent duplicate.

The model looks like:

```
class Autodamb(models.Model, Activity):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='highlight', null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    url = models.URLField(null=True)
    embed_donotuse = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    date = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    thumbnail = models.URLField()
    home_team_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    away_team_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


    class Meta:
            unique_together = ["title", "date"]
```

The views.py:

```
def save_damb_video(request):
    r = requests.get('https://www.brainxo.com/com-api/v1/?apid=xxxxxxxxxxx')

# data = json.loads(r)

data = r.json()


for x in data:

    title = x["title"]
    embed_donotuse = x["embed"]
    url = x["url"]
    date = x["date"]
    thumbnail = x["thumbnail"]
    home_team_name = x["side1"]["name"]
    away_team_name = x["side2"]["name"]

    user = request.user

    

    damb_data = Autodamb.objects.create(title=title,  embed_donotuse=embed_donotuse, url=url, date=date, thumbnail=thumbnail, home_team_name=home_team_name, away_team_name=away_team_name, user=user)
    
    damb_data.save()

return HttpResponse("DAMP API data successfully saved")
```

The problem is that the entire process would fail with a unique_together as some data already exist. Any Idea how to iterate and only save data not already existing while maintaining the unique constraint?

Comment: Just wrap it in a `try`-`except`? The `damb_data.save()` is not necessary by the way, since the `.create(..)` already does that.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem. With `try`-`except`, it will exit the process once it encounters the unique_together error and move to `except`. I am would like to save non-existing data instead of just exit the process.

Comment: no, you wrap only the `Autodamb.objects.create(...)` in the `try`-`except`, such that it continues with the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will ignore rows that have an already existing combination of title and date and just insert the rest.

```
objects = []
for x in data:

...

    damb_data = Autodamb(
        title=title,
        embed_donotuse=embed_donotuse,
        url=url, date=date,
        thumbnail=thumbnail,
        home_team_name=home_team_name,
        away_team_name=away_team_name,
        user=user
    )
    objects.append(damb_data)

bulk_create(objects, ignore_conflicts=True)
```

PS. I would recommend check out [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) if you're building an API in Django. It has Serializers for just this kind of thing.